# multiple condition in if statement

Tags: c

I have a line of code like this:

```
for (ivalue=list[i];i>0 && list[i-1]>ivalue;i--)
    ...
```

which runs fine. But if I change the position of first condition i>0 it exits with Segmentation fault: 11 while running:

```
for (ivalue=list[i];list[i-1]>ivalue && i>0;i--)
exits with Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why the results depends on position of conditions in && operator?

Comment: `&&` short circuits, thus if check for `i>0` fails then `list[i-1]` won't be executed and you won't be indexing an array with a negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suppose that `list[i-1]` is going out of the array bound.
When you are using `&&` the code check your first condition and if it is *true* it check the second, so in the first case `list[i-1]` is limited to access to `list[0]` because you first check `i>0` while in the second case you are checking for `list[-1]` before the `i>0` check and this give you the error!

Answer (score 2):

The order of Associativity of **&&** operator is left to right

So it first checks for `list[i-1]>ivalue` before checking `i>0`

Thus when **i=0** the `list[i-1]` becomes `list[-1]` that is out of bound and hence gives **segmentation error**

NOTE: `i>0` is never checked

Answer (score 1):

It is because with operator `&&`, if the first condition is evaluated to false, the second condition is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you chain multiple expressions with `&&`, in this case `i>0` and `list[i-1]>ivalue`, only the former one is executed when it evaluates to false.

Your second expression accesses an invalid index, should `i` be smaller than 1.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `list[i-1]` points to invalid memory (memory your program is not allowed to access) and if the first part of a `&&` statement in the conditional is evaluated as false, the second part never gets executed (This is called short circuit evaluation). This is why the first example works fine (in some cases), while the second example, where `list[i-1]` is actually accessed, gets a segmentation fault error.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) also has a nice article on short circuit evaluation.